# html5 websockets closing connect when a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, python, html, google-chrome, websocket

I use the javascript websocket to connect to the websocket server. I use python flask framework to navigate through webpages.

my project is as below:

1. the route "/" renders index.html page. In this page, I create a
   websocket connection.
2. when I receive data from the server, I navigate to different route (for instance: "/page/1")

When i click on the href link on my index.html page, i see the websocket is being closed.

I googled out and implemented 2 methods of persistent storage.

1. LocalStorage
2. Shared Web Workers

Both of them were not of any use, since, the websockets are being closed when i click on the href link. From this I think that persistent storage of websocket instance is not a solution to my problem (please correct me if i am wrong). Please suggest me the right approach to tackle my problem. Thank you in advance.

I am using the latest version of google chrome (52.0.2743.82)

Answer (score 0):

The WebSocket connection only persists as long as the page it was established for is open. Loading another page closes the WebSocket, so storing a reference to the object does not help (what it references no longer exists). You need to establish a new WebSocket connection after each page load. 
(For an older look into how the problems here, see http://tavendo.com/blog/post/websocket-persistent-connections/, and 10.2.3 in the HTML spec https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#shared-workers-introduction)